Why is this flight from Morocco to Saudi Arabia flying such a long detour?
I saw the following flight path for RAM2014 from Oujda to Medina by accident on Flightradar24. Why is it doing such a long detour to go to Medina?


I'll wait for the proper answer but usually that is because the intervening countries simply don't allow the plane and/or the airline through. Or the airline doesn't feel safe being in their airspace.

This is due to the closure of the airspace, as ratchet freak indicated.
I could find news reports from 2015 saying the airspace was closed:

Algeria closes airspace to Marocco, dated 2015
Marocco stops flights to Libya and closes airspace (likely reciprocated), dated 2015

Concerning Libya Al Jazeera indicates: "The Arab Spring and Gaddafi’s overthrow has made the security situation in Libya profoundly complicated"
However, it seems the situation is improving, as there are talks of opening flights between Marocco and Libya

Flight path from FlightAware with labeled FIRs

I believe there is a feature to see the airspace in FlightRadar24. If someone here has it, they are welcomed to add a picture of the Flightpath on top of the airspace borders

@fooot thanks!!
